# Why i get previous data in dialog using primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i don't know why i get previous data when i use dialog that i call it from datatable, when i open the dialog and leave required field empty and press edit when i close the dialog and open another row i notice that the old data is appear in the fields

here's my code

```
<h:form id="content" prependId="false">
            <c:set target="#{facilityMB}" property="facilityType" value="Recreation"/>
            <h:panelGrid class="ipmagix-mainFrom" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" columns="1">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="ipmagix-breadcrumb">
                    <ul class="breadcrumb">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
                        <li class="active">Recreation Promotion</li>
                    </ul>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="panel panel-primary">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="panel-heading">
                        <i class="icon-white icon-list"></i>
                        <i></i>
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.facilityRecreationList}"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="panel-body">
                        <p:messages id="messagesForList" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="false" closable="true"/>
                        <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="ipmagix-list-width" id="facilityListForm">
                            <ui:include src="facility-view.xhtml"/> 
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="panel panel-primary">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="panel-heading">
                        <i class="icon-white icon-plus"></i>
                        <i></i>
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.facilityRecreationAdd}" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="panel-body">
                        <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="false" closable="true"/>
                        <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="ipmagix-form-width form-horizontal" id="facilityAddForm">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <h:outputLabel for="facilityName" class="control-label" value="#{bundle.name}"></h:outputLabel>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <p:inputText value="#{facilityMB.facilityName}" id="facilityName" maxlength="40" required="true" requiredMessage="#{validation.emptyName}"  />
                                    <p:watermark value="#{bundle.name}"  for="facilityName"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <h:outputLabel for="language" class="control-label" value="#{bundle.language}"></h:outputLabel>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="language" value="#{facilityMB.languageId}">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{facilityMB.languageList}" var="lang" itemValue="#{lang.languageID}" itemLabel="#{lang.languageName}" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <h:outputLabel for="facilityDesc" class="control-label" value="#{bundle.description}"></h:outputLabel>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <p:inputTextarea value="#{facilityMB.facilityDesc}" id="facilityDesc" maxlength="100" style="width: 80%" autoResize="false" rows="3" required="true" requiredMessage="#{validation.emptyDescription}"  />
                                    <p:watermark value="#{bundle.description}"  for="facilityDesc"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="uploader" class="control-group">
                                <h:outputLabel  class="control-label" value="#{bundle.imageURL}"></h:outputLabel>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{facilityMB.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced"
                                                  update="uploader, messages" auto="true"  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>
                                </div>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <div class="control-group well well-small">
                                <p:commandButton id="saveFacility" value="#{bundle.save}" styleClass="btn btn-mini btn-primary" icon="ui-icon-plus" action="#{facilityMB.saveFacility()}"
                                                 oncomplete="filter();" update ="facilityAddForm, facilityListForm, messages">
                                </p:commandButton>
                            </div>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="uiBlock">
                <p:blockUI block="facilityListForm" trigger="saveFacility" >
                    LOADING<br />
                    <p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:ajax-loader.gif']}"/>
                </p:blockUI>
                <p:blockUI block="facilityAddForm" trigger="saveFacility" >
                    LOADING<br />
                    <p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:ajax-loader.gif']}"/>
                </p:blockUI>

            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
        <h:form id="dialogForm" prependId="false">
            <p:dialog id="dialog" modal="true" width="80%" resizable="false" header="Edit Special Promotion" widgetVar="dlg" dynamic="true">
                <p:ajax event="close" update=":content:facilityListForm" />
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="dialogContent">
                    <ui:include src="facility-edit.xhtml"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:dialog>  
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

and this is view page is be included

```
<p:dataTable widgetVar="tableVar" id="facilityDataTable" scrollWidth="100%" value="#{facilityMB.facilityList}" var="facility" paginator="true" editable="true" emptyMessage="#{bundle.emptyData}" rows="5" filteredValue="#{facilityMB.facilityFilterList}" >                               
        <p:column headerText="Image" width="100">
            <p:lightBox height="100">  
                <h:outputLink value="#">  
                    <img src="#{facility.imageURL}" width="100" height="100"/>
                </h:outputLink>
                <f:facet name="inline">  
                    <img src="#{facility.imageURL}" width="500" height="500"/>
                </f:facet>  
            </p:lightBox>  
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{bundle.name}"  sortBy="#{facility.facilityName}" filterBy="#{facility.facilityName}" rendered="#{facilityMB.facilityType != 'Special Promotion'}">
            <p:cellEditor >
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText id="ink" value="#{facility.facilityName}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{facility.facilityName}" maxlength="40" required="true" requiredMessage="The name is not valid"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column width="5%" headerText="#{bundle.language}" sortBy="#{facility.languageID.languageName}" filterBy="#{facility.languageID.languageName}">
            <h:outputText value="#{facility.languageID.languageName}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{bundle.description}" sortBy="#{facility.facilityDescription}" filterBy="#{facility.facilityDescription}" rendered="#{facilityMB.facilityType != 'Special Promotion'}">
            <p:cellEditor >
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText  value="#{facility.facilityDescription}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText value="#{facility.facilityDescription}" maxlength="100" required="true" requiredMessage="The description is not valid"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column width="2%">
            <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" immediate="true"
                           oncomplete="filter()" action="#{facilityMB.deleteFacility(facility)}" update=":content:facilityDataTable, :content:messagesForList">
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>
        <p:column width="4%">
            <p:commandButton id="basic" value="Edit" immediate="true" action="#{facilityMB.prepareEdit(facility)}" oncomplete="dlg.show();filter();" update=":dialogForm:dialogContent" >
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{facilityMB.selectedFacility}" value="#{facility}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `update=":dialogForm"` on edit command button. So whenever you open `dialogbox`, previous data will get refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Do not keep `p:dialog` inside `h:form`, instead keep `h:form` inside `p:dialog`.
Then you can update the `h:form` or any `h:panelGroup` inside `p:dialog`.
If you want to do it from Javascript use `loadContents()` function on `p:dialog`'s `widgetWar` object.

For Example:

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <p:commandButton update=":form2" oncomplete="myDialogWidget.loadContents()"/>
</h:form>

<p:dialog widgetWar="myDialogWidget" appendToBody="true">
    <h:form id="form2">
        ....
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: it didn't work i think the problem when i click on edit with empty required data the problem in the jsf validation